# Why would I prefer EX weapons over Normals with an elemental boost?

Tags: granblue-fantasy

In Granblue Fantasy, I'm having trouble understanding the use of EX weapons, specifically in the sense that there seems to be no way to boost their skill effect with a summon compared to Omega and even Normal skills/weapons. Yet, EX weapons are clearly recommended in (beginner?) grids. How come?

Answer (score 1):

The reason I can think of as of why EX weapons good for beginner:

- New player main summon is mostly a 0* (40%-100%) element boost summon from gacha. It's rare for a beginner to have a fully uncapped (120%) magna or primal summon. so it will have no difference in what kind of weapon mod they put in.
- SSR EX weapon is easy to get (easy to uncap). You can easily obtain fully uncapped SSR EX weapons by trade it from events or side story (means it's not based on luck like flip-chest or mvp chest or gacha).
- It's a good filler to raise until your basic magna grid is ready. If you don't have any magna weapon left to raise, it's okay to raise EX weapon rather than raise a random SSR gacha weapon which is mostly 0* (refer to wiki to decide whether to raise/reduce a gacha weapon, most of them is only good as fodder but sometimes it's very precious)
- Having 1-2 SSR EX weapons for each element is a must. You still use those weapon until you have a better EX weapon like Xeno or Hollowsky weapons.

But I think it's still better to farm and build basic magna grids if you can.

Comment: Interesting. Why are EX weapons a must though? Wouldn't regular ones be more potent coupled with the right (potentially borrowed) summon?